# Checking for Multiple Lines and Outputting what lines are missing. (Bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

So basically I have a file, for the sake of understanding how to write this, that looks like this.

```
Start:
       First line of text
       Second line of text
Bin:
       Third line of text
       Four  line of text
```

What I need to accomplish is write a script that checks for these strings and will output any missing strings.

Based on my assumptions I would assume this would involve an awk or grep that would check if each string and a set of if statements that would say if this doesn't exist then output what string doesn't exist.

Any pointers on how to start this? 
Here's what I've tried so far with that is little psuedocode-ish.
`

```
 str1=$(awk '/Start:/' /some/file)
 str2=$(awk '/First line of text/' /some/file) 
 str3=$(awk '/Second line of text/' /some/file)

if $str1 == '' then
   print $str1 'does not exist'
elif $str2 == '' then
   print $str2 'does not exist'
else $str3 == '' then 
   print $str3 'does not exist'
fi`    `
```

Comment: Can you show us your desired output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What constitutes a "missing string"?

Comment: do you know about the `diff` cmd? It should give you a standardized approach to finding differences in files. Maybe not exactly the format you have envisoned, but a common and std tool in linux/unix environments. Good luck.

Comment: A missing string means that when I check for a predetermined string such as the one in the variables above and its not in the file I need to output that its not there.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should print the missing strings with AWK:

```
BEGIN {
 a[i++]="Start:"
 a[i++]="First line of text"
 a[i++]="Second line of text"
}

// {
 for (s in a) {
  if (match($0,a[s]) ) { a[s]="" }
 }
}

END {
 for (s in a) {
  if (a[s] != "") { print a[s] }
 }
}
```